# Adding multiple row values into one row keeping the index interval as same as the number of row added in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, data-manipulation

I have a data frame with multiple columns (30/40) in a time series continuously from 1 to 1440 minutes.

```
df

time   colA  colB   colC.....
1        5    4      3
2        1    2      3
3        5    4      3
4        6    7      3
5        9    0      3
6        4    4      0
..
```

Now I want to  add two row values into one but I want to keep the interval of index 'time' same as the row number I am adding. The resulted data frame is:

```
df

time  colA  colB  colC.......
1       6    6     6
3       11   11    6
5       13    4    3
..
```

Here I added two row values into one but the time index interval is also same as 2 rows. 1,3,5...
Is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: shouldn't colC at time = 3 be 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way would be to group your data set every two rows and aggregate with using `sum` on your 'colX' columns and `mean` on your time column. Chaining `astype(int)` will round the resulting values:

```
d = {col: 'sum' for col in [c for c in df.columns if c.startswith('col')]}
df.groupby(df.index // 2).agg({**d,'time': 'mean'}).astype(int)
```

prints back:

```
   colA  colB  colC  time
0     6     6     6     1
1    11    11     6     3
2    13     4     3     5
```

Answer (score 0):

one way is to do the addition for all and then fix time:

```
df_new = df[1::2].reset_index(drop=True) + df[::2].reset_index(drop=True)
df_new['time'] = df[::2]['time'].values
```